# How can I filter arrays in mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have created database with two collections. Each of these collections connected with relations.
Here I want to pass one item _id and check whether it passed to other collection as foreign key. If it's passed, I want to filter all items which consist as _id. How can I do that. Here my mongoose query and screenshot of db. Thank you

```
route.get("/:id",(req,res)=>{
Vehicles.find({
    categories: [req.params.id]
}, (err, data)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

[image: MongoDB Screenshot]

PS: For an example I want to get all vehicles which have category id "60c58c2dcf82de0780051378" inside categories array.

[image: MongoDB - category collection]

Comment: Can you share a sample JSON data from both the collections?

Comment: @hhharsha36 I updated question with new ss. can you check it please?

Comment: Please share sample input in JSON instead of screenshot and expected output. Its difficult to interpret by screenshot reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the mongo [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/), you can query for all documents where `categories` is an array that contains the objectId `req.params.id` as one of its elements.

```
Vehicles.find({
  categories: req.params.id,
}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```